# Probably a circular import in django app?

Tags: django

There is a filter that adds to form django_crispy_form functionality. All arguments passing as string divided by ",".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

#args=[url_name, submit_button_text, optional_<pk>]
@register.filter
def with_submit(form, args):
    sargs = args.split(',')
    action, name = sargs[:2]
    if len(sargs) > 2:
        args = sargs[2:]
    else:
        args = None
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    if args:
        #there exception throwed every time if len of args > 2
        helper.form_action = reverse(action, int(args[0]))
    else:
        helper.form_action = reverse(action)

    helper.add_input(Submit(action, name, css_class='btn btn-primary'))
    form.helper = helper
    return form
```

When I use this filter without third optional argument - it works fine, but when I add third <pk> argument - it crashes and says:

```
The included URLconf '1' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

And I don't know where I should find circular import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the `reverse` method is:

```
 reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)
```

So, your second argument of `int(args[0])` is being passed in as `urlconf`, which is leading to the exception. You need to use

```
 reverse(action, args=int(args[0]))
```

Whenever you write template tags or filters, you have to be very careful that you code is as simple and as robust as possible. Custom tags and filters are the most difficult parts of a django application to debug.

Consider this line:

```
action, name = sargs[:2]
```

This line will raise `ValueError` if there aren't exactly two items in `sargs[:2]`. You should do a check first before executing this statement.